# Timing safe comparison of strings

Tags: string, security, tcl, hmac

Does Tcl have any built in function for comparing strings in a timing safe manner, so no secrets are leaked because of short circuits?

`string equal` starts from the left and returns on the first difference, so it's not suited to compare secrets.

Specifically, I want to compare two `sha256` HMACs. Double HMAC would also solve the leakage, but I want to find a timing safe comparison function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are dealing with two strings of the same length (e.g., HMACs) then you can just apply a comparison to each character and accumulate the result:

```
proc safeequal {s1 s2} {
    set equal 1
    foreach c1 [split $s1 ""] c2 [split $s2 ""] {
        set equal [expr {$equal & ($c1 eq $c2)}]
    }
    return $equal
}
```

Now, there might be some timing effects due to `split` doing character sharing, but they'll be *really* difficult to exploit to determine the content of the strings as the timings won't be identifiable with a position and will in any case be down in the noise. I can't make my system anywhere near quiet enough for me to see a difference even between comparing two strings (of about HMAC length) that are equal at every character and comparing two that are different at every character.

```
% time {safeequal qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm} 100000
9.847818689999999 microseconds per iteration
% time {safeequal qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM} 100000
9.78685247 microseconds per iteration
% time {safeequal qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm} 100000
9.72245421 microseconds per iteration
% time {safeequal qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM} 100000
9.88214891 microseconds per iteration
```

Comment: I think I'll add a length check, but otherwise it's Good Enough™.

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use a usual bitwise `or` combined with a per character `xor`.

```
# Timing safe comparision of two hashes.
# 
# http://stackoverflow.com/q/35090706/2373138
proc hash_equals {hash1 hash2} {
    # Get length of strings a single time.
    set hash1_length [string length $hash1]
    set hash2_length [string length $hash2]

    # If the length is not equal, return false.
    # Short circuit if they have different lengths.
    # Length of the hashes is anyway known and length information
    # will always be leaked because of caching effects.
    if {$hash1_length != $hash2_length} {
        return 0
    }

    set result 0

    # Loop through the entire string and compare each single character.
    # We compare using XOR to avoid timing effects on if branches.
    for {set i 0} {$i < $hash1_length} {incr i} {
        set char1 [string index $hash1 $i]
        set char2 [string index $hash2 $i]

        # Convert character to its ordinal value.
        set ord1 [scan $char1 %c]
        set ord2 [scan $char2 %c]

        # Wil be 0 as long as they're the same.
        set xor [expr {$ord1 ^ $ord2}]

        # Once $result is not equal to 0, it will stay not equals 0.
        set result [expr {$result | $xor}]
    }

    # Strings are exactly equal if $result is exactly 0.
    return [expr {$result == 0}]
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "length information will always be leaked because of caching effects" above your early return? How can I find out more?

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit faster if the strings are equal, but it doesn't matter time-wise if the first difference is at the beginning or at the end.

```
proc compare {a b} {
    set ary($b) 0
    set ary($a) 1
    set ary($b)
}
```

This works too (it's still a hash table):

```
proc compare {a b} {
    dict get [dict create $b 0 $a 1] $b
}
```

Comment: @kelunik: But if the only information leaked is that the strings are equal, maybe that doesn't matter very much, since you are already giving that away.

Comment: I guess the hash table lookup is optimized just like `string equal`.

Comment: @kelunik: however it is optimized, it doesn't give out information about where the difference occurs in a mismatch.

Comment: I'm not sure about Tcl's internal hash table implementation, but I think it uses standard string comparison once collisions appear. Additionally, it's a detail that can change at any time.

Comment: @kelunik: there isn't going to be any collisions. There is one single lookup, and it's going to end up in its own bucket.

Comment: Any hash function might collide for `a` and `b`. Since the hash function and `a` are known and there's a timing difference, it's easy to reduce the search space to collisions. Once a collision occurs, usual string comparison is used which short circuits on the first difference. This makes it possible to use timing differences there. See also http://wiki.tcl.tk/5164. I'm no expert, so I think I'm sticking with the known implementation from PHP ported to Tcl for now.

Comment: @kelunik: and again, when I time this there aren't any such differences. But it's certainly your call.